# RSpec testing module methods/

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd, stub

I have next modules.

```
module A
  module B      
    def self.method_b(value)
      #code
    end
  end 
end
```

and

```
module A
  module C
    def self.method_c(value)
       A::B.method_b(value)
    end
  end
end
```

How to test these module? How to create stub self.method_b?

spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.mock_with :mocha
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: `A::B.stub(:method_b).and_return("whatever")`

Comment: `NoMethodError:undefined method 'stub' for A::B:Module`

Comment: Seems like a bug in RSpec to me. `#stub` should be available on all objects :-\

Comment: Look my `spec_helper.rb`. It may be something to add in spec_helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have switched out the built-in RSpec mocking library for mocha. That has a different [API](http://rdoc.info/github/freerange/mocha/frames). Try:

```
A::B.stubs(:method_b).returns('value')
```